# Sequelize transaction - save transaction to commit in the next request

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working with a feature to bulk upload more than 1000 users to DB
Many insertions have to be done in different tables for each user

To avoid a timeout I am dividing the upload csv file in chunks of 200 lines and sending each chunk to the backend.

My problem is:

if I have something wrong with the data, and it was not catch by the middlewares, the application crashes. If it crashes in the third chunk, for example, all data from the 2 previous chunks were already inserted in DB.

I need an all or nothing approach. If the application crashes for some reason nothing should be inserted in DB.

Is there a way I can save or acumulate the sequelize transactions until the last chunk is completed and only then commit all transactions at once??

appreciate any suggestion

Comment: So you're only streaming to avoid a timeout, where comes that timeout? it's from `fetch` or `axios` api client? To try to keep it simple i would put a higher timeout and do that in a single step, in that step you open a transaction, and if everything goes right you `commit` that transaction, if it goes to the catch block a `rollback` should be invoked. So this is not a streaming solution, also for upload file you use multer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB transactions. Db transactions won't cause timeouts (But they may cause deadlocks if you misuse them)

You can use the following Promise for example;

```
 execInTransaction: function (pool) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                logger.debug("Connection opened " + connection.threadId);
                if (err) return reject(err);
                connection.beginTransaction(function (err1) {
                    if (err1) return reject(err1);
                    
                    // Loop and insert 200 items at each time.. 
                    
                    connection.commit(commitError => {
                        connection.release();
                        if (commitError != null) {
                            return reject(commitError);
                        }
                        return resolve("<some result>");
                    });
                }).catch(txnError => {
                    connection.rollback((rollbackError) => {
                        connection.release();
                        if (rollbackError != null) {
                            logger.error("Connection rollback failed. " + connection);
                            return reject(rollbackError);
                        } else {
                            return reject(txnError);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
```